# Magento2 : UI select and search dropdown value dependency in admin

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I have two custom customer attributes which I have shown as select & search dropdown in admin customer edit form.
For e.g
**Attribute A and Attribute B**

**I want**: When I select any value from *attribute A* dropdown then it will update it's corresponding values in dropdown *attribute B*. This should also work on page refresh on the basis of pre-selected value of *attribute A*

**I already tried** : Get corresponding values of *attribute B* from value selected in *attribute A* via ajax call. Got stuck in populating those value in *attribute B*.

Any help would be appreciated.